# Close votes were removed by deleting duplicate question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/37155/20) had at least two close votes when last I viewed it.  Now it has none. It appears this is the result of FMS deleting the "possible duplicate" question [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/37130/20).

A sneaky move on his part! This apparently magically deleted the close votes. But this question is still a near exact word-for-word duplicate of the (now deleted) question, and thus should likely be closed for the same reason: put on hold as too broad.

I see two problems here:

1. The deletion of the dupe question should undo the VtCs on the remaining question. [This feature request already exists on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200391/165502).
2. It appears FMS is being entirely disingenuous with this question. This is literally the *third* time he has tried to ask essentially the same question (the first time it was about Christians in general, now he's narrowed it to Catholics, but it's still completely devoid of meaningful definitions). Rather than listening to the comments on his questions, from multiple users, he's gaming the system to keep his question open--to what end, I don't know.

Myself, and several others, have offered suggestions to improve his question, but he refuses to adjust his question.

It seems to me the question needs to be closed (*again*) until these problems are addressed.

Comment: Were *all* the VTCs retracted because of the deletion, or just the ones with "duplicate" as the reason? If a question is off-topic it should be VTC'd for being off-topic, not for being a duplicate, even if it is one.

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude: Presumably just those as duplicate (which were apparently all of them). Proper procedure is to vote identical questions as duplicate, even if duplicate of a closed question.

Comment: wax eagle just told me in chat: "if it's OT just close as ot...doesn't matter on the dupe and dupes are more restrictive"

Comment: @Mr.Bultitude: Sure, that's appropriate, too. We can't expect all close voters to know of all possible duplicates before VtCing as off-topic. That doesn't mean it's wrong to VtC as a duplicate.

Comment: *Myself, and several others, have offered suggestions to improve his question, but he refuses to adjust his question.* - This is not how it come across especially from you. I am just trying to have questions asked and to me you are giving my posts a hard time. Please see [our chat here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20912/fms-flimzy) and you and [DavidStratton's action here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/37161/according-to-catholic-theology-male-and-female-is-to-man-as-blank-is-to-god?noredirect=1#comment103479_37161).

Comment: (Cont.) I do not believe a subjective deficiency e.g. not understanding a question scoped from a perspective, especially when one does not belong to that perspective, is reason enough to give "heat" to a post let alone undertake some of the actions you have taken. You might learn something to let a question be answered and thus help promote the aims of the site.

Comment: PS I will let others weigh in on the general tone of your post and its accusations/labeling.

Comment: @FMS: I'll admit that my patience with you has worn thin, but this is not because I don't "like" you, or because I'm "picking on you," its because after months of interaction, you consistently show the same disregard for this community's guidelines and practices, and continue to insist on doing things "your" way. I'm sure you're a swell guy, and if we were to have a coffee together, we'd get along quite well. But on this site, my continual impression is that you blatantly disregard anyone who disagrees with you.

Comment: @FMS: In the last 2 days you have received 22 downvotes. Three were mine. If you discount my three, that's still 19. That's more than all the downvotes o fall other [highly active users](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/users) *combined*.  You have 22, tho others (from the first page of the link) have a combined 13. I'm not picking on you. You are continually producing low-quality content, according to the entire community.

Comment: I'm going to vote this down since A) it makes sense to me that VTC's as duplicate have to be removed when the old question is deleted, and B) though I agree with your frustration, @Flimzy, I take issue with your tone.  I don' think public shaming is the way to handle this.  If it's a big enough problem, moderators have tools at their disposal.  Short of that, if you don't like a question, VTC and move on.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: I *did* VtC. My VtC was removed, due to FMC's belligerent behavior. That's the whole point of this post. This post is my attempt to move on.

Comment: Post undeleted. Not sure how Flimzy would come to the conclusion I was *sneaky* or *gaming the system* etc. I just deleted a post that's all. How am I [was I to know] what were the after-effects of a such deletion? In any case *Has there been a reported instance of a Christian with near-death experience who has testified seeing figures of other religions? [closed]* was the original question I wanted to ask. This should refute his *This is literally the third time he has tried to ask essentially the same question*.

Comment: @FMS: I'm not specifically accusing you of deleting the previous question *for the purpose of removing close votes*. I *am* suggesting that your deletion of the original question is an attempt to obscure the fact that you are refusing to address the core issues brought up by the community. Asking a duplicate question is never the appropriate way to resolve a closed question. You've been told this. Repeatedly. You continue to ignore this, and insist on asking duplicate questions anyway.

Comment: PS If I recall correctly, I have also deleted a question post after receiving feedback Flimzy that it was poorly researched. I ackowledged that was the case and deleted. Again, not sure of where he bases his claims in his post. As i have said before, there is at times more that what meets the eye. I don't worry because it is Christian belief things eventually manifest themselves. Truth always comes to the fore.

Comment: **You've been told this. Repeatedly. You continue to ignore this, and insist on asking duplicate questions anyway.** [My comment shows that's not the case] -  This seems to be the goal because after that has been established even by perception however wrong, an action will follow ...

Comment: [correction in the PS] after receiving feedback Flimzy ...  - After receiving feedback **from** Flimzy ...

Comment: @FMS: `This question should actually be deleted, because it's an exact duplicate of one which has already been closed.` ([comment on your dupe question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/37155/in-catholic-church-history-have-there-been-any-extra-biblical-reports-of-vision#comment103189_37155)). So what did you do? You deleted the *other* question. If your goal is to make me think you're acting in good faith, you're not doing a good job.

Comment: I disagree it was an exact duplicate and the community has not not yet agreed with AndrewWelch. My point here is what my question was put through. Please read my comments carefully. The first post of this matter was prompted by NDE experience and people seeing Jesus. It should be evident **that** question and **current** question are **NOT** duplicates [even remotely] and that I have tried very hard to make edits (can easily be shown from revisions on each question) incorporating feedback from comments and trying to comply with site requirements (Cont.)

Comment: (Cont.) and the end result is the same [I can't get to ask my question] and worse, I am the one cast in bad light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this behavior is now [prohibited](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2015/02/february-2015-newsletter-in-progress/#flagsuppress) across the entire network.